# How to get GIF from MKV interval?

Tags: extract, video-conversion, matroska, gif, frame

I'm looking for a piece of software (free or not) that will allow me to load a .mkv video (and other video types, not just .avi), and tell it to extract frames as images from within a certain interval.

If it can also create a proper quality gif out of that array of images, very well, if not, I can do it myself.

I used to do this with irfanView and it's multimedia plugin, but it only supports avi files, even though it can play mkvs.

Do you know of such programs? I have searched google far and wide and don't seem to find anything, except software that would convert the entire video to a small sized gif. (like formatFactory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qyDCnxFN3WE), using Adobe Premiere you can set width and height.

Comment: Alison Brie, mmmmm... Oh, the tutorial, right! Thanks, I was hoping to not have to install premiere cause I'm not sure where I put the kit, but it's probably the best solution when it comes to quality...

Comment: Sorry, but this is a link-only answer that links to a YouTube video that is now marked as private 11+ years later and thus not accessible to anyone without logging into YouTube.